# Extensions change TCA in ext_tables.php Check for ExtensionManagementUtility and $GLOBALS["TCA"]

Tags: typo3

> **Extensions change TCA in ext_tables.php**
>
> Check for ExtensionManagementUtility and $GLOBALS["TCA"].

During upgrading `typo3` version 7 to 8
How to solve this?

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're the owner of this extension, it is recommended to migrate the TCA changes into the extensions' folder `Configuration/TCA/` for new TCA tables, and `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/` when adding fields or manipulating TCA.

This way, all changes from `ext_tables.php` should be moved in there, due to a better performance in frontend. See also this change:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78384-FrontendIgnoresTCAInExtTables.html